# Pine Script: How to check if current time is 3:00 PM in GMT+5:30 timezone

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

In the PineScript v5, I am trying to develop a strategy where I don't intent to take any trade
after 3:00 pm (in GMT+5:30 timezone). So if the current time is less than 3:00 pm, then only I will "entry"/"exit" the trades. Otherwise at 3:00 PM, I want to exit all the open positions.

So I tried this:

```js
endOfDay = input.int(defval=1500, title="Close all trades, default is 3:00 PM, 1500 hours (integer)")

if (hour(timenow) < endOfDay)
    // Entry
    float sl = na
    if (sureBuyInTrend)
        strategy.entry("enter long", strategy.long, lotSize, limit=na, stop=na, comment="Long")
        sl = atrLow
    if (sureSellInTrend)
        strategy.entry("enter short", strategy.short, lotSize, limit=na, stop=na, comment="Short")
        sl = atrHigh

    // Exit: target or SL
    longExitComment = (close < sl) ? "Long SL hit" : sureSellInTrend ? "Long target hit" : "Long close"
    shortExitComment = (close > sl) ? "Short SL hit" : sureBuyInTrend ? "Short target hit" : "Short close"
    if ((sureSellInTrend or (close < sl)))
        strategy.close("enter long", comment=longExitComment)
    if (sureBuyInTrend or (close > sl))
        strategy.close("enter short", comment=shortExitComment)

lastBarOfDay = (hour(time_close)*60 + minute(time_close)==(60*(endOfDay/100)+endOfDay%100)) ? 1 : 0
if (lastBarOfDay)
    // Close all open position at the end
    strategy.close_all(comment = "Close all entries")
```

The 'close all entries' are working fine.

However I am seeing the `hour(timenow) < endOfDay` check is not working.

In the List of Trades I am seeing order is issued at 3:15 PM.

What mistake I am doing here?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can calculate the hour in GMT+530 using below code

```
h=hour(time('1'),"Asia/Kolkata")
m=minute(time('1'),"Asia/Kolkata")
hour=h*100+m
```

Then you can use this hour in your if case instead of hour(timenow)

In below chart I have plotted both (my calculated hour (above) and hour(timenow) (below)) in GMT+530

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Worked! I just used syminfo.timezone instead of hard-coding to Indian context. Thanks a ton.